# Access normal text using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="top_l">
    <a class="shou" onclick="" href="">11</a> | 
    <img border="0" class="" src="/">XXXXXX<a href=""></a> | 
    <a href=""></a> | 
    <a href=""></a> 
</div>
```

How do I get the text XXXXXX using jQuery(what selector to be used)?

Comment: do u always has that <br/> by the end of XXXXXX

Comment: can you show the parent html tag where xxxxx resides ?

Comment: @arjuncc well, that was just for indicative purpose. By the way when I checked back, I always have an <a> tag having no id or class besides that text.

Comment: @UjjwalManandhar yes, it's a div with a fix-class, but there are a couple of tags more as a child after which the text is present.

Comment: could u pls update that anchor tag in your question? and could you please specify that parent of <img> as @Ujjwal Manandhar said

Comment: @arjuncc It's this way `<img src = "abcd.png" /> XXXXXX <a href="/usercp.php">some text</a>`

Comment: The entire sample structure as followed:

`<div class="top_l">
 <a class="shou" onclick="" href="">11</a> | 
  <img border="0" class="" src="/">XXXXXX<a href=""></a> | <a href=""></a> | <a href=""></a>
  </div>`

Answer (score 2):

You can only select element nodes with jQuery. And most jQuery methods only consider element nodes, so using jQuery and plain DOM API together might be a good approach here.

The text node you want to target is the next sibling of the image. So if you can get a reference to the image element, you can access the text node with the [`.nextSibling` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Node.nextSibling) property:

```
var txt = image.nextSibling.nodeValue;
// or if image is a jQuery object
var txt = image.get(0).nextSibling.nodeValue;
```

Given the structure of the HTML, you could do something like this:

```
var txt = $('.top_l > img').get(0).nextSibling.nodeValue;
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnTAD/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to put it inside an html tag and call that tag using jquery, see sample below.

```
<img src = "abcd.png" /> <span>XXXXXX</span> <br />etc etc<and some more HTML code>
```

and in your jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
alert($("span").text());
});
```

in jquery you can use css selectors to select the tag

```
<img src = "abcd.png" /> <span id="theText">XXXXXX</span> <br />etc etc<and some more HTML code>

$(document).ready(function(){
alert($("#theText").text());
});
```

Comment: I don't have access to that code. Please provide me solution that can be applied without changing the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
var childNodes = document.querySelector("div").childNodes, pickNext = false;
for(var i in childNodes) {
    var childNode = childNodes[i];
    if(pickNext) {
        alert(childNode.nodeValue);
        break;
    }
    // same as $(childNode).is("img")
    // now you can put the XXXXXX where ever you want.
    // as far as you know which is the next sibling.you can get it
    if(childNode.nodeName === "IMG") {
        pickNext = true;
    }
}
```

by this way you can find the text anywhere it is as long as you know the sibling's node type.

DISCLAIMER: this may not work in IE.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Avinash_R/ecUxQ/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You have plenty of solution, I add one more :)

```
var divVar=$(".top_l").clone();
divVar.children().addClass("remove");
divVar.children().remove(".remove");
var txt=divVar.html();
txt=txt.replace (/\|/g, '');
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/arjuncc/HgcDH/3/)